# Devise not working since i18n installation

Tags: ruby-on-rails

my sign-in & sign up pages are no longer working since I installed the i18n translation to my app. 
(the rest of app was working perfectly in English/Chinse/French until I sign-out)
I have modified my routes to

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  scope "/:locale", locale: /#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")}/ do
    devise_for :users
    resources :users, :only => [:show, :edit, :update]
    resources :users do
      resources :profile
    end

    get 'users/show'
    get 'users/:id' => 'users#show'
    get 'users', to: 'users#index'
    get 'users/update'
    get 'users/index'

    root to: redirect("/%{locale}/posts", status: 302)
  end
  root to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}", status: 302), as: :redirected_root
  get "/*path", to: redirect("/#{I18n.default_locale}/%{path}", status: 302), constraints: {path: /(?!(#{I18n.available_locales.join("|")})\/).*/}, format: false
```

BUt i still have the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in UsersController#show
Couldn't find User with 'id'=sign_in
```

Is there anything that should be changed for Devise to work ?

Comment: can you run `rails routes` in the console and post the output?

Comment: I have modified the question to have the routes.

Comment: Routes are processed in order-it's interpreting 'sign_in' as the ID since it matches the pattern for your resource route first. You can reorder your routes, set parameter regexes, etc.

Comment: @Etienne Great, glad to hear it :)